# UIPageViewController subview disappear while page change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uipageviewcontroller

I'm writing an UIPageViewController based application over which view I placed a subview:

```
[self.view addSubview:fontViewController.view];
```

This view fade in and out when I tap on the center of the main view (the pageviewcontroller one). When this view is shown, I don't want that disappears when I change the page. I think that this subview should be added to a layer over the main view and not to the view itself. Am I wrong? If not, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What is the parent of the main view? 
In some cases this might work:

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:fontViewController.view];
```